# Showing busy progress bar using Ext JS

Tags: extjs, progress-bar, messagebox

I want to show the busy progress bar using Ext JS. I am using `Ext.MessageBox.wait()` with title as 'busy' for showing busy message box , I am closing the progress bar  using `Ext.Msg.hide()`  in my custom java script.

It is showing the progress bar, But there is a product specific (my application) script is loading in between which causes the progress bar to be closed. The product script is closing the message box using hide method. I can not able to control or edit the product specific script.

I want to close the message box only with my custom java script code.

Please suggest how to proceed with this. Is there any other way to show & hide the busy progress bar, So that i can get rid of the product specific `Ext.Msg.hide()` calling?

Many thanks in anticipation..!!

Regards,

Uday.

Comment: Can you share the relevant bits of code? I'm not sure how you can't control the 'product specific' script, even though you say it's your application.

Comment: The script that is calling by the product script is var successHandler = function(obj){
    nsUI.common.closeAlert();
    //validate session
      if (nsUI.common.validateSession(obj)) {
        p_callback.success(obj);
      }
  }; which inturns calling nsUI.common.closeAlert = function() {
  //if (nsUI.common.alertDialog)
    //nsUI.common.alertDialog.hide();
  if(typeof(Ext) != "undefined"){
   Ext.Msg.hide();
  }
};
 Its actually hiding the progress bar which is shown by using my script. I can not control any of the above code.

Comment: We'll need more than that. This doesn't show what your code is actually doing. --never mind, just saw the rest.

Comment: Sry, I just updated my first post with correct Ext JS calls. Can I use Ext.MessageBox.progress() instad of wait() ?? Will Ext.Msg.hide() also closes the progress() ??

Comment: Yes, hide() will close Ext.Msg.progress() as well.

Comment: Can the code that you can't control be modified (I'm assuming it's global code for your company?) to accept some kind of argument to override? Or can you make the processing of your custom script be a part of a callback from the code that you can't modify?

Comment: No, I can not modify or edit the product code, even I can not use the callback in product code. Please let me know if there is any other simple way of showing progress bar without using the message box?